# PostgreSQL Timezone conversion

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I am running PostgreSQL 9.4 and am having issues converting the timezone correctly in my queries. The server that is updating the DB is an XMPP Chat Server and the column in question is `sent_date` which is datatype `timestampz`.

Firstly, I test that the conversion works from UTC to AEDT statically (first without conversion, then with):

```
tcmadb-pub=> select '2016-02-24 05:52:58.686893'::timestamp with time zone;
          timestamptz
-------------------------------
 2016-02-24 05:52:58.686893+00
(1 row)

tcmadb-pub=> select '2016-02-24 05:52:58.686893'::timestamp with time zone AT TIME ZONE 'AEDT';
          timezone
----------------------------
 2016-02-24 16:52:58.686893
(1 row)
```

However, when I run the actual query, I only see the data as timestampz and not as the timezone time:

```
SELECT sent_date 
FROM jm 
WHERE 
    from_jid like 'user1@domain.com%' AND 
    sent_date::timestamp with time zone AT TIME ZONE 'AEDT' BETWEEN '2016-02-23' AND '2016-02-29';
           sent_date
-------------------------------
 2016-02-23 22:13:33.858971+00
 2016-02-23 22:13:31.458917+00
 2016-02-23 22:13:26.186859+00
 2016-02-23 22:13:46.347431+00
 2016-02-23 22:22:33.483243+00
 2016-02-23 22:22:38.482727+00
 2016-02-23 22:22:35.929189+00
 2016-02-23 22:23:15.196597+00
 2016-02-23 22:24:19.257813+00
 2016-02-23 22:23:39.746997+00
 2016-02-23 22:24:14.382916+00
 2016-02-23 22:24:45.410786+00
 2016-02-23 22:23:58.929407+00
 2016-02-23 22:28:46.33302+00
 2016-02-23 22:28:52.141082+00
 2016-02-23 22:29:16.330865+00
 2016-02-23 22:58:33.798908+00
 2016-02-23 22:58:33.795771+00
 2016-02-24 03:06:11.60482+00
 2016-02-24 03:06:31.276288+00
 2016-02-24 03:07:07.885728+00
 2016-02-24 03:14:31.630305+00
 2016-02-24 03:14:31.632573+00
 2016-02-24 05:16:21.757124+00
 2016-02-24 05:16:21.760133+00
 2016-02-24 05:51:38.791875+00
 2016-02-24 05:51:38.794093+00
 2016-02-24 05:52:58.686893+00
(28 rows)
```

This has never worked before so I'm guessing something with my query is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the timezone of `sent_date` only in the `WHERE` part.

You also have to do this the `SELECT` part, like:

```
SELECT sent_date::timestamp with time zone AT TIME ZONE 'AEDT'
  FROM jm
  WHERE from_jid like 'user1@domain.com%' 
    AND sent_date::timestamp with time zone AT TIME ZONE 'AEDT' BETWEEN '2016-02-23' AND '2016-02-29';
```

Comment: Thank you @OcuS that was it